# Can I back up and restore my FTL save file?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

FTL shares many similarities with roguelikes, especially in that you can't save and load your game easily.  However, you can save and quit.

Sometimes I get into a really good position and then die due to some random bad luck.  Occasionally I'd like to experience an event multiple times to see what the outcome is.  It would be nice if I could somehow save state and restore later if I choose.

Is it possible to back up this save file and restore it later?  Where is it stored?  Is there anything in particular I would have to do to the file in order for it to be recognized by the game?

Comment: You can backup your save, but no matter how you wash afterwards, you'll never feel clean!

Comment: The problem with beginning to save scum is knowing when to stop. It starts with restoring to avoid bad luck, but back luck is part of the game, so the save scumming quickly spreads to other parts of the game.

Comment: I've been save scumming roguelikes for 20 years, but...  I... I can quit anytime I want!  Really!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that steam *does* sync your FTL achievements and unlocks.

Comment: Why is everyone honking about the villainy of saving? Games are meant to let *us* do what *we* want to achieve maximum enjoyment. Not to pursue some holy grail. Some people... have jobs!

Comment: @bharal I could not agree with you more!

Comment: There's a legitimate reason to backup a save state, which is that FTL has been known to crash - leaving the player with 4 hours down to experience!  They deliberately delete the save state after loading it, but if going to do that should have a "crash handler" that can save the recent state of the game.  It's not FTL rocket science :p

Comment: meanwhile,
* * * * *  exec >/dev/null 2>&1 ; cd ~/.local/share/FasterThanLight/ ; git add -A ; git commit -m .

Comment: Haha, I entered Engi sector as the first sector, leaving the starting one and the first encounter was a pirate who blasted away my ship in 3 shots, nobody tells me I should have spent my money otherwise to prevent this happening. This game sucks, only saving makes it bearable.

Comment: Confirmed that this editor allows you to rename your crew. http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=10959

Comment: @bharal Well I respect your view but many people probably don't treat games this way. So you definitely can't speak for everybody about what games mean. Also frankly the roguelike elements are no more and the game becomes much less enjoyable if you just constantly S&L. Anyways you already got ridiculously OP ships now if you just want to go on to have some "invincible" feeling. TBH in my first playthrough with FTL I cheated a lot to unlock all ships. It just felt like I didn't achieve anything at all so I'm deleting my profile and starting anew this time.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

On Windows 7, you can find it under `My Documents\My Games\FasterThanLight`. But only after you've clicked *Save+Exit*.

But please be aware, that this uncertainty is what makes rogue-like games so enjoyable. I just needed this to copy my career from my laptop to my PC, as the game doesn't seem to support the Steam Cloud.

Comment: Enjoyable here meaning "Truly Frustrating"

Comment: it is less enjoyable if your real bad at this game yet still enjoy it. 10 playthroughs later and i still haven't finished it. got to the end boss 3 times, died twice on the 2nd, once on the first. not to mention the amount of time i've been hoping not to run into anything but a shop at 3 hp. Although the risk is fun, i'd like to, beat the game once :P. (And all this on easy)

Comment: @Andy - on that note, 'Easy' doesn't change anything except the score at the end and the amount of loot/scrap you get from events/battles.

Comment: I would say go ahead and use not only save scumming but also memory cheats (like tsearch or cheat engine). Once you've satisfied your curiosity about completing the game you can keep playing it without any saves/cheats. :P

Comment: @Andy: I beat the final boss on the first time I fought him, you have to have used most of your scraps on upgrades. If you spent too much on buying weapons or drones you will be too weak. Do not forget to pause when overwhelmed.

Comment: @BlueTrin: If you've got enough firepower to take out the boss missiles in the first round, you don't need much else.

Comment: Do you really need to click Save+Exit?  I checked immediately after exiting a sector (without clicking that button) and noticed my ae_prof.sav and continue.sav had modified dates from just a few seconds ago.

Answer (score 54):

In Linux, the savegames are stored in `~/.local/share/FasterThanLight`.

Answer (score 36):

On OS X you can back up the 'continue.sav' file from here:

```
/Users/[your user name]/Library/Application Support/FasterThanLight
```

Make a duplicate of it on your desktop and then restore it if necessary.

As has been said, though, this kind of defeats the purpose of the spirit of playing a roguelike. Permadeath is a feature, not a bug. ;)

Comment: I disagree. I can still have the joy of the nerve-wracking "Will I make it", but be able to restart from a key point, rather than back to the first baby steps.

Comment: Also, it allows you to experiment a little with things. I dared leap my units onto an auto-scout. DO NOT LEAP YOUR UNITS ONTO AN AUTO-SCOUT. Suffocation is a horrible way to go.

Comment: And finally, thanks so much for this answer, as it helped mitigate the BLASTED SEGFAULT I got on sector 8.

Comment: We can agree to disagree on the saving thing, that's the beauty of it being a game. Also, leaping units onto an auto-scout can be potentially viable if your transporter is upgraded enough so that the cooldown is shorter than your unit's lifespan in an oxygen-free environment. Sending a couple of Crystals or Rockmen over to take out the weapon system can be a life-saver.

Comment: True. Tried to do it with a type 1 teleporter and a human. That was the mistake.

Answer (score 10):

### For Windows Users :

You can use this script to load/save your game (See the code below).
Just copy the script into a text file with your favorite text editor.
Then save it in a `.bat` file like `LauncherFTL.bat` then put this file into your game folder.

Launch the game with `LauncherFTL.bat` afterwards and use the menu to save/load your game.

```
:init
@echo off
set saveFolder=%userprofile%\Documents\My Games\FasterThanLight
set saveFile=continue.sav
set backupFile=continue.bak
set saved=1
set loaded=1
:choixLauncher
cls
@echo Menu FTL
set choice=
set /p choice=(S)ave/(L)oad/(F)TL/(Q)uit:
if not %choice%=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if %choice%==s goto fctSave
if %choice%==S goto fctSave
if %choice%==l goto fctLoad
if %choice%==L goto fctLoad
if %choice%==f goto launchGame
if %choice%==F goto launchGame
if %choice%==q goto :eof
if %choice%==Q goto :eof
goto choixLauncher
:fctSave
cls
if exist "%saveFolder%\%saveFile%" (
    if exist "%saveFolder%\%backupFile%" (
        call :choixSave
    ) else (
        echo Creation nouveau backup..
        call :save
    )
) else (
    echo Pas de fichier a sauvegarder...
)
goto launchGame
:fctLoad
cls
if exist "%saveFolder%\%backupFile%" (
    if exist "%saveFolder%\%saveFile%" (
        call :choixLoad
    ) else (
        echo Restauration du backup..
        call :load
    )
) else (
    echo Pas de fichier a restaurer...
)
goto launchGame
:launchGame
@echo Lancement de FTL
start /wait FTLGame.exe
goto choixLauncher
:choixSave
@echo Ecraser l'ancien backup ?
set choice=
set /p choice=(Y)es/(N)o:
if not %choice%=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if %choice%==y goto save
if %choice%==Y goto save
if %choice%==n goto launchGame
if %choice%==N goto launchGame
goto choixSave
:save
copy "%saveFolder%\%saveFile%" "%saveFolder%\%backupFile%"
set saved=%errorlevel%
goto :eof
:choixLoad
@echo Ecraser la sauvegarde actuelle ?
set choice=
set /p choice=(Y)es/(N)o:
if not %choice%=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if %choice%==y goto load
if %choice%==Y goto load
if %choice%==n goto launchGame
if %choice%==N goto launchGame
goto choixLoad
:load
copy "%saveFolder%\%backupFile%" "%saveFolder%\%saveFile%"
set loaded=%errorlevel%
goto :eof
```

Comment: This is the best and most complete answer in this whole post, excellent! It's funny how it starts in English and ends up in French :D

Answer (score 7):

You can backup the save file and restore at a later point if you die.
The save 'files' are located in 
/My Documents/My Games/Faster Than Light/prof.sav
and
/My Documents/My Games/Faster Than Light/continue.sav
Copy those two somewhere, and when you need them just put them back. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can save and restore your progress by backing up the 'continue.sav' which is generated every time you press Save & Quit. Details here: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/FTL:_Faster_Than_Light#Quicksaving

The save games are located here: `\%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Games\FasterThanLight\`

Comment: This adds no new information.

Comment: Not true. It does mention the exact save file in that folder.

Comment: FWIW, %USERPROFILE% actually expands to C:\Users\ (username), making the C:\Users\ redundant. And actually, if you happen to install Windows on the D drive, it's wrong. So for those of you looking to copy and paste in the address bar: %USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Games\FasterThanLight\