# Can I have multiple Saves?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If I save and quit a game, can I start a new game to show my friend the game from the beginning without erasing my current game?

Comment: My Documents\My Games\FasterThanLight See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83428/can-i-back-up-and-restore-my-ftl-save-file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, by [savescumming your old game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83428/can-i-back-up-and-restore-my-ftl-save-file). That's the only way though, if you don't backup your old save and start a new game it will be gone.

Comment: +1: Good use of an existing answer to answer a new question