# Copying non-steam FTL save to Steam

Tags: steam, ftl-faster-than-light, linux

I have been playing FTL for a while, and managed to unlock all the ships. Recently, however, I managed to get a copy on steam. I would like to just copy my save from the linux directory (i.e. `~/.local/share/FasterThanLight/prof.save`) to my steam account, to keep everything in sync.

However, when I go to my Steam folder, no such file exists to replace.

How can I copy my existing save into Steam?

Comment: Where you have it now should be fine, have you run the game via Steam? It should look it up from that directory. Steam (from what I can see) loads the game normally and doesn't force the save to any other directory.

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure you installed FTL on your computer (the one you want to move the save into).

In the "~/.local/share/FasterThanLight" directory, you should see 2 files:

- continue.save
- prof.save

Copy both of these files, and paste them into the "~/.local/share/FasterThanLight" on your new computer. If there are no files there, than that probably means that you simply haven't unlocked anything on that copy of FTL; **simply replace any files there, or add them in if there are currently none.**

---

If you are *not* moving the saves between computers, then don't do anything. Steam uses the same directory for saves as the non-Steam version, so you can simply click "Play" in Steam, and keep your saves.

Comment: If you are on Mac OS X  the saves are found at `/Users/[your user name]/Library/Application Support/FasterThanLight` (originally seen in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/84596/15416)).