# Is the Crystal Cruiser quest guaranteed?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I'm trying to unlock the Crystal Cruiser, and am on step 2 of the [Ancestry](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ship_Achievements/Ancestry) quest, heading to step 3. I have already:

> (1) Found the damaged stasis pod and (2) repaired the stasis pod and had a Crystal alien added to my crew.

Happily, the very next sector for me is the Rock home sector, but **no quest marker ever appears in that sector**. According to the [version 1.03.3](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Patches#Version_1.03.3) change log (which happens to be the version I am running):

> If you're carrying the Crystal alien from the stasis pod, the Rock Homeworld map will start with the appropriate quest marker for the beacon that leads to the Crystal sector.

I don't see that quest marker, and multiple attempts with this save file (which I [backed up](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/83428/can-i-back-up-and-restore-my-ftl-save-file) ... I know, I know!) have never given me the appropriate quest randomly. I should also point out that I have an active quest in the current sector that I am opting to skip. Could that be the source of my troubles?

Comment: Dumb question but you are sure its a rock home sector and not border sector?

Comment: The sector simply identifies itself as "Rock controlled sector" on the jump map. Is that the wrong place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, upon further inspection, the next sector in my game is a "Rock controlled sector" not the "Rock Homeworlds". As a result, the quest marker doesn't appear because **I'm in the wrong place**.

Comment: that's right.  It should say rock homeworld sector if it really is a homeworld sector.